# How to use cheats in retropie?

Tags: retropie

I am following [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/3kthv6/having_lots_of_trouble_trying_to_get_cheats_to/?) link and copied cheats to `/home/pi/RetroPie` but when I goto RGUI I don't see any cheats option. The link says:

> You open the retroarch menu, go to core cheat options and load the cheat file. Then flip the cheat you want to the "on" option and press apply cheat changes. When you resume the game, the cheats will be on. Also, genesis cheats do not seem to be supported/working.

but when I open retroarch menu I don't see any cheat options. I also don't have any cores loaded - whatever they are but am able to play games without them. Could anyone paste a screenshot of the cheat options?

Comment: similar: http://blog.petrockblock.com/community/members/antagony/forums/replies/

Comment: could someone move this to gaming.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to `/Home/pi/.config/retroarch/cheats/`

Then the GameConsole (hit `ls` to see what GameConsoles) than the cheat name. I edit with `sudo vi (cheat name).cht`.